# Unsolved issue with str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

(Sorry... the "_" won't accept between str (and) replace in this posting Title)

I had not done any Regexp stuff for several years, and went into gridlock trying to figure out what to do.

Then I ran across a code snippet using str_replace as a possible option, and decided to give that a go.  Now I'm in "StucksVille".

The objective is to reformat incoming data for a Java App to a PHP page, and clean-up the data into regular .csv appearance and also write that data to a .csv file on the server.  There are 12 fields in each data record.

(Incoming Data)
csv=data%2Cdata%2data%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%0D%0A

This is what I'm attempting to do:

```
Delete/Remove beginning csv=
Replace all %2C with , (a comma)
Replace ending %0D with \r  (carriage return)
Replace ending %0A with \n  (newline)
```

Here is what I came up with, but the test.csv file data still looks the same as the (uncleaned) original {SIGH}.

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

$cleaned1 = str_replace("\xcsv=", "\x", $entityBody);
$cleaned2 = str_replace("\x%2C", "\x,", $cleaned1);
$cleaned3 = str_replace("\x%0D", "\x\r", $cleaned2);
$cleaned4 = str_replace("\x%0A", "\x\n", $cleaned3);

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'a+');

fwrite($fp, $cleaned4);

fclose($fp);
```

Any assistance or guidance is appreciated.

-Stucko

Comment: Can you explain what those `\x` all over the place are supposed to achieve?

Comment: I think you just need to remove `\x` from all your calls to `str_replace`

Comment: Why do you need `str_replace()`? Your input string is a fragment of a query string, it is URL encoded. Use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to get the actual value then process it as you wish: https://3v4l.org/5OcB5

Comment: why u dont use urldecode ?

Comment: @axiac you should post that as an answer

Comment: Really appreciated all the helpful info everyone.   I was in a fog here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `urldecode()` that will do almost all of that for you

```
$in = 'csv=data%2Cdata%2data%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%0D%0A';
$in = str_replace('csv=', '', $in);
$clean = urldecode($in);
echo $clean;
```

RESULT

```
data,data-ata,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `str_replace()` or `regex`. Your input string is a fragment of a query string, it is URL encoded and PHP provides the tools to handle it properly.

You can use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to get the actual value then process it as you wish:

```
$input = 'csv=data%2Cdata%2data%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%0D%0A';
echo(urldecode($input));

# The output is:
# csv=data,data-ata,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
```

Even better, you can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) instead and it will also take care of the `csv=` part (because this is what `parse_str()` does for a living; it parses query strings):

```
$input = 'csv=data%2Cdata%2data%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%2Cdata%0D%0A';
parse_str($input, $pieces);
var_dump($pieces);
```

The output is:

```
array(1) {
  'csv' =>
  string(60) "data,data-ata,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data,data
"
}
```

If you also need to parse the CSV string into pieces then you can pass it to [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$fields = str_getcsv($pieces['csv']);
var_dump($fields);
```

The output:

```
array(11) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [1] =>
  string(8) "data-ata"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [3] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [4] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [5] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [6] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [7] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [8] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [9] =>
  string(4) "data"
  [10] =>
  string(4) "data"
}
```